# HTaccess condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to match certain rules Only when there is no "locale" in the query string

Here is how i am doing it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !locale
RewriteRule ^acceuil$ home.php?locale=fr [NC,L]
... (More rewrite rules)
```

Basically i want `/acceuil` to go to `home.php?locale=fr` (Working perfect)

Except that if somehow a link was like this `/acceuil?locale=en` i would like to make it go instead to `/home` which is equivalent to `home.php?locale=en`

Any chance to rewrite lets say "`/acceuil`" in the following way :

```
if(isset($locale)) {
      go to home.php?locale=$locale
}
else{
      go to home.php?locale=fr
}
```

Also i am wondering if the condition should be copy pasted before each rule ?

Please let me know if this is possible, and how i can get it going, if you have some useful reference for htaccess rewrites please share :)

Thanks

Comment: If it's French then it's **`Accueil`**, *not* `Acceuil` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic rule that should work, and that makes sure the variable in the GET is `locale` (not `localeee` neither `llllocale`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)locale=([a-zA-A]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^acceuil$ home.php?locale=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

# if locale = en ...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)locale=en(&|$)
# ... and it goes to home.php then go back to /home:
RewriteRule ^home.php$ /home [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

Note: if it's French then it's **`Accueil`**, not `Acceuil` :)

Comment: thanks i appreciate your help and thx for catching the typo :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}  !locale
RewriteRule     ^acceuil$               home.php?locale=fr  [L,NC]
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}  locale=([a-zA-Z]{2})

RewriteRule     ^acceuil$               home.php?locale=%1  [L,NC]
```

**Edit:**
First condistion just check the presence of `local` in  query string. If it's not, rewrite URL to `home.php?locale=fr` and if there is `locale=`, it takes  whatever is after that(only two characters) and put them in `home.php?locale=%1`  so `acceuil?locale=fr`  means `home.php?locale=fr`. And `acceuil?locale=en` means `home.php?locale=en`.

There are two conditions and two rewrite rule:-D

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! By this logic i understood that conditions apply ONLY to the one rule am i right ?